# Using html-pdf with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

Currently I am testing [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) module to generate pdfs from html. And I have successfully generated one. But the issue is that the text/data in the html is fixed at the moment.

What I am trying to do is have an html form on the front-end which the user fills and then generate a pdf which includes the content the user typed.

What I have done so far:

```
app.post('/pdf',function(req, res) {

  pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
     console.log(res);
   });

});
```

Is this possible using html-pdf? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not generate the pdf on the time of save click ?

Comment: @CodingDefined Yes I could do that but still how would I pass the users data to the `pdf.create` which takes a `html` file as an argument to convert to pdf. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Why not take a scree shot of the web page when the user click on save. Take a look at http://www.codingdefined.com/2016/01/capture-screen-of-web-pages-through-url.html

Comment: // please check solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70889057/how-to-generate-pdf-from-dynamic-html-and-upload-it-to-aws-s3-bucket-without-dow/73166410#73166410

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `html-pdf` module can't handle the dynamic data. You can take a look at the [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) which does the screen capture.

In fact, `html-pdf` module uses "phantomjs" at background. However, it uses the small feature of phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [dynamic-html-pdf](https://github.com/navjotdhanawat/dynamic-html-pdf)

Just follow the steps:

1. Install using this command `npm install dynamic-html-pdf --save`
2. Create html template
3. Create pdf with below code:

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var pdf = require('dynamic-html-pdf');

   var html = fs.readFileSync('template.html', 'utf8');

   pdf.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, v2, options) {
   if (v1 === v2) {
       return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
   })

   var options = {
    format: "A3",
    orientation: "portrait",
    border: "10mm"
   };
    //Your dynamic data 
   var users = [
    {
       name: 'aaa',
       age: 24,
       dob: '1/1/1991'
    },
    {
       name: 'bbb',
       age: 25,
       dob: '1/1/1995'
    },
    {
       name: 'ccc',
       age: 24,
       dob: '1/1/1994'
    }
   ];

   var document = {
    type: 'buffer',     // 'file' or 'buffer'
    template: html,
    context: {
       users: users
    },
   path: "./output.pdf"    // it is not required if type is buffer
   };
    pdf.create(document, options)
    .then(res => {
       console.log(res)
    })
   .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was finding solution for the same and got around one.

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-generate-dynamic-pdfs-using-react-and-nodejs-eac9e9cb4dde

you can checkout this work around done in the blog.
He simply called a function that returns an HTML string and he use backticks for dynamic data.